# Make regular expression Python

Tags: python, regex

I cannot deal with the conditions in regular expressions.
I need to find everything:

```
<script type="text/javascript">9089089089</script>
<script>9089089089</script>
```

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="python_files/py_dict.js"></script>
```

My regex is not working properly.
Please tell me how to do it?

```
re.compile(r'<script.*(?<!src$).*?>(.*)</script>')
```

I need to find all the `<script>` tags that do not contain the `src` attribute and display the code that is inside the tag.

Comment: What do you intend yo extract ?

Comment: <script>If the condition is true, get between the tag</script>

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to extract. Can you actually add what you want as output?

Comment: Should not be src attribute

Comment: Do you want to just get all the attribute names and values in the script tag *if* there is no *src* attribute inside it? Please just add expected output to the question.

Comment: Why regex when you can use any xml parser?

Comment: Optionally, a regular, important standard modules ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on a regex-based solution:

```
(?s)<script\b((?:(?!src).)*?)>(.*?)</script>
```

[Python code](http://ideone.com/hZ2nBz):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?s)<script\b((?:(?!src).)*?)>(.*?)</script>')
test_str = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"python_files/py_dict.js\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">9089089089</script>\n<script>9089089089</script>"
print [(x.group(1), x.group(2)) for x in re.finditer(p, test_str)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use BeautifulSoup to find the script tags setting `src=False`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print(soup.find_all("script", src=False))
```

It will return the script tags without the src attribute:

```
import  requests
r  = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414867/make-regular-expression-python/30414987#30414987")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print(set(soup.find_all("script")).difference(soup.find_all("script", src=False)))
{<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>, <script src="//cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=f07e1c0b90d5"></script>}
```

Comment: @Strelok2014Strelok, why can't you use BeautifulSoup, is this homework?

Comment: I am developing a portable app, I need a minimum of dependencies, and to parse the tags 3, BeautifulSoup pretty big ...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that there is probably a python package that will work more elegantly for your application. However, if you really want to use a regular expression, just look for the script tags:

```
re.compile(r'<script>(.*)</script>')
```

When you do a `re.search` (or `re.match`) will return `None` if there's an src attribute in the line.